# Grafana text panel: Picture streches when rezising the window

Tags: html, css, image, grafana

**I have a grafana text panel** which is showing a picture i got out of the internet. Within the html code i tried to manipulate that picture with the height width and object-fit adjustment so if i resizes the window it wont strech.

```
<img src="https://example-picture.png" 
style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;">
```

**The problem** now is that if i safe that panel and resize my window it streches my picture.

**I inspected the picture** itself with my web-browser and the element style filter showed me that the object-fit: contain command was not saved.

**The question** for me now is if grafana is only receiving the html part after object-fit is a css property ? Or is there a work-around?

My grafana-cloud is running v8.5.2. on a linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

Set `disable_sanitize_html = true` in the Grafana config https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/administration/configuration/#disable_sanitize_html so Grafana won't sanitize your custom HTML code. Then `object-fit: contain` should be used.

Comment: Hi there Jan, is this also working for grafana cloud ?